# Error:Could not autoload puppet/type/ec2_instance: /etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:31:

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, puppet

Does anyone have experience with getting the puppetlabs-aws module to work? I am running:

- Puppet 3.7.5
- Centos 6.5
- Ruby 1.9.3p551

Following the [readme](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/aws/readme) on the forge.

I should be able to run commands like

```
puppet apply tests/create.pp --test
puppet apply tests/test.pp --test
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
*Error: Could not autoload puppet/type/ec2_instance: /etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
  newparam(:name, namevar: true) do
                          ^
/etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:227: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
Error: Could not autoload puppet/type/ec2_instance: /etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
  newparam(:name, namevar: true) do
                          ^
/etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:227: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end on node ********************
Error: Could not autoload puppet/type/ec2_instance: /etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
  newparam(:name, namevar: true) do
                          ^
/etc/puppet/modules/aws/lib/puppet/type/ec2_instance.rb:227: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end on node ***************
```

In addition from the readme, I should be able to run commands like

`puppet node_aws list`.  But I keep getting:

> that the subcommand node_aws is unknown

.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of the aws module do you have installed? Run `puppet module list | grep aws`

Comment: Hi Peter,I have version 1.0.0 installed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up the Cloud Provisioner and the AWS module.

The `node_aws` command is from the [Cloud Provisioner](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/cloudprovisioner_aws.html) (which is now deprecated).

Comment: Peter, thanks for clearing that up.  Do you have any experience using the AWS module?

Should i be able to run commands like
puppet resource ec2_securitygroup and
puppet resource ec2_instance

The errors I posted above is what I get when I run the puppet resource commands above.

Comment: I do! Have you installed the AWS module and setup the credentials? Do `puppet module install puppetlabs-aws`, then after that try `puppet resource ec2_instance`. You'll need to setup your credentials first (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-aws#installing-the-aws-module)

Comment: @panxincheng Are you able to resolve this error? I am also facing the same error.